# Get a value from a parent Block

Tags: magento

I'm facing some difficult to accomplish this apparently easy task.

I'm in a nested block ( suggestion.phtml ) and I want to get a value ( number of search result, and so the collection count) from a parent block ( result.phtml )

I'm wrong or there is not an easy way here ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok solved.

It is possible to access a parent block with:

```
$this->getParentBlock();
```

So in this particular scenario:

```
$searchCount = $this->getParentBlock()
    ->getParentBlock()
    ->getParentBlock()
    ->getResultCount();
```